# How to update table with SQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a trigger that will update a table based on what is inputted into another table. Basically it's supposed to see what kind of cuisine the user inputted and then update the tally in another table. Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStats AFTER INSERT ON Restaurant
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE RestaurantStats SET TotalRestaurants = TotalRestaurants + 1 WHERE Cusine = NEW.cusine;
END$$
```

For some reason though I keep getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: Be careful when tagging your questions. sql-server <> mysql.

Comment: Does that mean you can't help me either.....

Comment: Does the UPDATE statement work outside the trigger?

Comment: Do you have a table called NEW?  Where are you getting NEW.cuisine from?

Comment: @MikeS, `NEW` is an alias for `Restaurant` - the table which the trigger is defined on.

Comment: @MikeS: [Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)